# Unexpected select dropdown behaviour with vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, drop-down-menu

If I remove `background-green` class binding or `value` binding from the `select` element then it works as a normal dropdown. But let's say I didn't remove the `background-green` class binding then after selecting, the selected option is not displayed but if I select again the same selected option or other option then it would be displayed. Same behavior with `value` binding. So why it's working second time? This is my real concern/confusion.

Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-fog-637bu?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) of running example with sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a mixture of `:value="defaultValue"` not actually changing (because `defaultValue` never changes) and also a side effect of a rerender happening the first time.

Since `:value` is essentially always `""`, any time the `<select>` is re-rendered, Vue sets the value to that empty string.

You have `handleInput` set `fillBg = true` which triggers a re-render, because `background-green` was not in the initial render. This means Vue will reset the value of the `<select>` back to `defaultValue` (blank)

During the time it *appears* to work after the first selection, what's actually happening is DOM local state showing what you selected. Since there is no change to the vdom (background-green is already there), Vue is *not* re-rendering and thus not resetting the value.

The proper way to fix this is to either update `defaultValue` (perhaps rename this) during the input event or use [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html). The point is to have Vue set the proper value any time it renders.

```
handleInput(e) {
  this.fillBg = true;
  this.defaultValue = e.target.value;
},
```